# Webbrowser - Clicar em elementos de um site

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-basic-6, navegador-de-internet

Olá, pessoal!

É o seguinte, preciso fazer com que o meu programa clique em um elemento. Aqui uma foto para facilitar a compreensão:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3GTj.png

Já tentei muitas coisas, mas nada de sucesso até agora...
Quero que o botão seja pressionado

O meu código está assim até agora:

```
Dim PageElement1 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("")
    For Each CurElement1 As HtmlElement In PageElement1

        If (CurElement1.GetAttribute("classname") = "preferred-login facebook-login") Then

            CurElement1.InvokeMember("click")
            MsgBox("Deu Certo")
        End If

    Next
```

Mas o "click" não dá certo...
Bom, se alguém puder ajudar...
Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode obter o elemento pela classe e clicar nele sem a necessidade de iterar todos os elementos da página.

```
webBrowser1.FindElementByClassName("preferred-login facebook-login").Click();
```

Ou usando o seletor By.ClassName:

```
webBrowser1.FindElement(By.ClassName("preferred-login facebook-login")).Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando o código:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("")
```

Você está pegando todos os elementos da página que tem o `name` atributo de `""`. Ou seja:

```
<div id="id" name="bobagem"></div> <!-- não encontrado -->
<div name=""></div> <!-- encontrado! -->
<div name="" id="id2"></div> <!-- encontrado! -->
```

Comment: Então pessoal, tentei de muitos jeitos, mas o problema não é encontrar o elemento, o problema mesmo é clicar nele. Não está clicando... Alguém pode tentar fazer uma aplicação que clique no botão de login pelo facebook do site pt.stackoverflow e me mandar um exemplo para eu estudar?

Comment: @WesleySilva cara, você pode também fazer o Selenium rodar um comando JavaScript que clique no botão para você.

Answer (score 1):

Estive tentando resolver o mesmo dilema que você enfrentou, ou ainda enfrenta, e por sorte, realizando uma pequena modificação no seu código, consegui realizar o clique no botão.

Obs1: Tive que preencher o `GetElementsByName("COLOQUEI O NAME DO BOTÂO ALVO")`.

Obs2: Tive que retirar o `If ...`, e aí funcionou.

```
Dim PageElement1 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("COLOCAR O NAME DO BOTÃO ALVO")
For Each CurElement1 As HtmlElement In PageElement1

        CurElement1.InvokeMember("click")
        MsgBox("Deu Certo")

Next
```

Desta forma funcionou para mim, espero que lhe seja útil. Um abraço e obrigado.